# Visual Basic and MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with visual basic to run macro operation in MS Excel.
On running the application sometime it crashes or terminates due wrong input given or other reasons. Now it shows a dialog to asking to Continue, Debug, End or Help.

So i Need to disable Debug option from that or it just terminates showing error as on selecting debug will take user in Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications.

The debug option in my opinion is from MS Excel as after selection on End option it shows my application Error Handler.

please share your experiences and suggestion to disable this DEBUG option while application is running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you see that message, your code has an error.  When you choose 'debug', the yellow highlighted line is the line with the error (probably).  Can you edit your post and include the code? Maybe we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'll want to handle all of your errors via the code itself; meaning that if your code throws an error or has received an improper input, the program will display a customized error notifying the user of the issue, or ignore the error. Simple example:

```
Sub ErrorHandling()

On Error GoTo DisplayMessage:
x = 0
y = 5 / x
GoTo TheEnd:

DisplayMessage:
MsgBox "Your x value cannot be 0"

TheEnd:
End Sub
```

The code will throw an error because you can't do 5 / 0, but the error will be handled by going to the `DisplayMessage:` part of the code. However, if you really do need to disable the "Debug" button, you can do the following:

1. Open up the VBA Editor
2. Right-Click on the name of your project (if you haven't changed it, it should be "VBAProject")
3. Select "VBAProject Properties" (Where VBAProject is the name of your
   vba project)
4. Select the Protection tab and then check "Lock for project viewing".
5. Enter a password. This password will now be required if you want to open the VBA Editor make further edits to the vba code

Save and close your workbook

Now the next time you open the workbook and an error occurs, the debug button will be disabled.